# How can i make my email as verified like PayPal

Tags: ssl, smtp, server, exchange-server

How can i make my email as verified like PayPal, even though my URL and exchange server is having **SSL** certificate its still going to spam folder.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3070163?hl=en

> ...who match the following criteria:
>
> - Send a high volume of messages over time that most Gmail users think are not spam.
> - Publish a DMARC reject policy, which means that the domain only sends authenticated mail and any unauthenticated mail sent by the domain should be rejected.

Which means in effect that

- You have to be important for lots of users, so that they need to be protected from phishing mails claiming to be you.
- And you have to properly controlled the delivery of your email, that is have published DKIM, SPF policies to control who should be able to send email with your domain and how to proof that these emails where delivered by your domain. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC.